# multivariate modelling of survey data

Tags: clustering, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

I’m having trouble figuring out the best analytic approach to use.

I have survey data that measures people’s sustainability behaviours – there are seven of these, for example: eating organic, recycling, buying green products etc. Behavioural frequency is measured at two time points. There is a fairly large n (=631).

I want to assess the extent to which the degree of change in frequency in each behaviour over the two time points is associated with change in the other behaviours.

A basic analysis could look at correlations between behaviour change measures. So, for example, is Δbehaviour1 associated with Δbehaviour2? This can easily be done using a correlation matrix.

I could also look at a series of linear regressions. This would entail estimating the equation (1) Δbehaviour1 = constant + β(Δbehaviour2) + β(Δbehaviour3) + β(Δbehaviour4) etc. and then the equation (2) Δbehaviour2 = constant + β(Δbehaviour1) + β(Δbehaviour3) + β(Δbehaviour4) etc. up to the total n of behaviours.

This seems unsatisfying, however, and intuitively wrong!

What I really want to do is to look at the relationship between each of the variables as a whole, so that any estimation of an association between changing behaviours takes into account the relationships between all the variables.

I hope this makes some sort of sense. I feel like the main reason I have difficulty here is that each of the behavioural indicators is neither an IV or DV (or is potentially both) and in each case may be associated with the others.

The best analogy I can think of is looking at health behaviours over two time points. If we consider smoking, drinking alcohol, exercising, sleeping, eating healthily – then a change in any of these could be linked to a change in any of the others, with a causal relationship that goes either way (or is due to some third factor). In that case can any pattern of change be examined without predetermining IVs/DVs?

Thanks for any help!